# Paw: response body size

Tags: paw-app

[Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw) shows a bunch of great information about a request / response including response time, but I don't see a field for request and/or response size. Is there a way to easily show the size of the response body in Paw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually can see the body size as reported by the server in the `Content-Length` header, though it is sometimes missing in case of a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` response.

There's a dynamic value to get the actual body length of the latest response, as shown below, but it isn't so convenient if you just want to see it yourself (not use it in a subsequent request):

[image]

*But thanks for the input, we will add a "body size" field in the next version!*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The response I was looking at happens to have `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` so a "body size" field would be lovely.